# Can't understand relationship of Celery Tasks to Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery

I am using Django to listen to voice commands. I was going to use Celery as a way to run a seperate process for listening, and a seperate process for executing commands.

When I had set up Django with Celery, I had envisioned starting Django (./manage.py runserver) and having those two processes initiate at startup.

But so far I see that the Celery app is started via the shell, and Django speaks to it seperately.

A HUGE part of my learning curve here is understanding what relationship Django has to Celery. I had intended to have everything running within the Django environment -- ie, not having Django run beside Celery.

Can someone tell me where I've become confused?

Answer (score 0):

Celery is a stand alone process that django hooks into and communicates over a socket.  That means celery will not run in the same process.  You will have to start celery as a separate process and add "workers" that will read messages off of the queue and handle the workload.  At the end of the django celery docs it shows you how to start a celery worker: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process.

That same page has some good tutorials on how to get started using celery:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps

Comment: No, communication doesn't happen over a socket. It happens via the broker: eg RabbitMQ or Redis.

Comment: Well, both of those are socket based communication. It does happen via the broker of your choice.